# discoloration with external monitor connected via mini displayport converter to htmi, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, displayport

I have two external monitors. The laptop lid is closed. One monitor is connected via VGA. The other is connected by way of a minidisplay port adapter to HDMI. The VGA connected monitor has no issues. The other monitor, has discoloration. The discoloration comes and goes and may change over time. My graphics hardware is Intel Haswell Mobile on a Thinkpad T440.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed cables and it seems to be working without discoloration now. I went from using a minidisplayport to hdmi adapter and hdmi cord, to using a cord with a minidisplayport connector on one end and an hdmi connector at the other.